# Cube Texture disappearing after some time

Tags: textures, webgl, three.js

I have made a cube with a texture and text on it.  When I rotate the cube, after some time, the texture disappears and a very nice colorful cube appears.

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slaver113/QfdyJ/2/) to view the problem:

I am using the latest version of firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your color is specified incorrectly. Do this instead:

```
cubeTextures.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, transparent: true, color:0xffffff } ) );
```

You have an array out of bounds. Do this:

```
context.fillText(cubeText[indexTexture], 20, 20, cubeWidth - cubeTextMarginLeft - cubeTextMarginRight);
```

I could not reproduce your problem with my browser, but see if this fixes it.

Edit: Your camera's field-of-view is 400 degrees. Yikes! Try 40.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer! I have tried your changes, but unfortunately it did not solve this weird issue, wich can be reproduced, if you wait let's say worst case a minute...

Comment: Here is a screenshot which might help you: http://www1.picturepush.com/photo/a/10528884/640/10528884.jpg

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue using Firefox 15.0.1 on OSX.

Comment: The problem is, that the cube is rendered correctly at the beginnging, but after several tweens, the text and the white surface disappears and the colorful rainbow appears. Tested on latest Chrome/Firefox Windows7

Comment: I have made another example where th effect happens more often: http://www.sebastianviereck.de/ (the animation on the top left corner)

Comment: It works fine for me on OS X with Chrome and FF. Why not make a new post with a simple, and correct, JSFiddle -- and provide screenshots. See if anyone else can reproduce it.

Comment: updated jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/slaver113/QfdyJ and screenshot: www1.picturepush.com/photo/a/10528884/640/10528884.jpg

Comment: i can confirm that the bug is not appearing in mac os

Answer (score 0):

seems like it was a bowser problem, it has disappeared now in the Firefox 24

Comment: Thank you for your Help WestLangley!